# $1$-form on a symplectic manifold.

Tags: symplectic-geometry

If $\omega$ is a $1$-form on a symplectic manifold, will it be closed?  It seems to be trivial that if $\sigma$ is symplectic structure on a manifold $M$, then the induced map 
$$\sigma^\vee: TM\to T^*M$$ is an isomorphism. Hence there exists some vector field $X$ such that 
$$\omega(Y)= \sigma(X,Y)$$
As $d\sigma=0$ implies $d\omega=0$. I don't see a mistake here. Is is true?

Comment: You can surely give an example of a non-closed $1$-form on $\mathbb R^2$...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mistake is that $d\sigma = 0$ does not imply $d\omega = 0$. By Cartan's formula, we have that
\begin{align*}
d\omega = & d(\iota_X \sigma) & & \\
 = & \iota_x d\sigma - \mathcal{L}_X \sigma & & \text{(Cartan's formula)} \\
 = & - \mathcal{L}_X \sigma, & & \text{($\sigma$ is closed)}
\end{align*}
where $\iota_X$ is the interior product with $X$, so that $(\iota_X \sigma)(Y) = \sigma(X, Y)$ for all vector fields $Y$, and $\mathcal{L}_X$ is the Lie derivative with respect to $X$, which by definition is
$$\mathcal{L}_X \sigma = \left.\frac{d}{dt} \phi^\ast_t \sigma \right|_{t = 0},$$
where $\phi_t$ is the flow generated by the vector field $X$.

So if every $\omega$ were closed, then we would have that every vector field $X$ on $M$ is such that $\mathcal{L}_X \sigma = 0$, *i.e.* every vector field on $M$ is symplectic. But there is a one-to-one correspondence between flows and vector fields, and the flow of a symplectic vector field is a one-parameter group of symplectomorphisms. This of course is an incredibly strong requirement that is not often satisfied by any manifold $M$ (if ever).

Comment: Moreover, the standard symplectic form on $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ is $d\lambda$, where $\lambda = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i dy_i$, so $d\lambda \neq 0$.

Comment: In response to your (if ever), the answer is never (unless $M$ is 0 dimenisonal).  For, if $M$ is symplectic and dimension $\neq 0$, then its dimension at least 2.  Then, in a small neighborhood of $M$ with coordinates $(x_1,..., x_n, y_1,...,y_n)$, one has the form $\omega = x_1 dy_1$.  This obviously doesn't have $0$ differential.  To get a form on the whole manifold, cut it off with a bump function.

Comment: No manifolds has all its $1$-forms closed. Closedness is a local property, so it is enough to give an example in $\mathbb R^n$ where it is easy.